# None of the request are getting authenticated in oauth spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to create a spring security based restful webservice.But I am not able to authorise any URl.
All the url are returning results without access token can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Below are the code details:-

1] GreetingController

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting1/greeting",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestBody User userregister) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(template, "aa"));
    }



}
```

2] ResourceServerConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
            ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/greeting1/greeting").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/greeting1/greeting").authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                        .authorities("USER")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .secret("123456");
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }

    }

}
```

3] WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /*@Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
      }*/

}
```

4] WebInitializer

```
public class WebInitializer extends org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

4] pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dhobilocker</groupId>
    <artifactId>DhobiLocker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>DhobiLocker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post error message and response message with response code

Answer (score 0):

change order of ResourceServerConfiguration  like this

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableResourceServer
public  class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.antMatcher("/api/mobile/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/mobile/user/avatar/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/mobile/hello").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/mobile/secure").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

            // @formatter:on
    }

}
```